# Mac-catalyst - minimum window size for Mac catalyst app

Tags: macos, uikit, ios13, mac-catalyst

Mac catalyst allows to resize window, is there any way to provide minimum window size for Mac catalyst app?

Comment: [This article](https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20190607-Beyond-the-Checkbox-with-Catalyst-and-AppKit) looks promising.

Comment: _Update_: The solution in the previously linked article actually worked for me.

Comment: Oh great, can you share demo code for it might be?

Comment: I'll try to create a demo project but probably not this week as I'm in vacation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add the following chunk of code to your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method (for **UIKit** projects) or to `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` (for **SwiftUI** projects):

```swift
UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
    windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
}
```

*PS: you can also set the `maximumSize` property there*

*PS2: If you set both `minimumSize` and `maximumSize` to the same value, the window size will remain static and won't be resizable.*

Comment: How to get the window size of the iOS App when it runs on Mac? The width, because the height corresponds to the laptop screen height. It is understood that the iOS App is not running in full screen on the Mac.

Comment: Is this still working? I tried to run this code also adding maximumSize but I'm able to resize the window at will in Mac Catalyst

Comment: @r4id4 I found that upon `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` the window scenes won't be setup yet so it wouldn't work; add a delay makes it work fine

Answer (score 15):

Here's an expanded version of @marcelosalloum's excellent answer..

**Step 1.** 
Open *AppDelegate.swift*

**Step 2.**
Locate *func application()*, insert your version of @marcelosalloum's code here (or make a call to a function your create for this, as I did).

**Step 3.**
Optionally assert that your code only run on platforms with the suitable Swift API's (use *#available*)

---

### Example Code (In *AppDelegate.swift*)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    addWindowSizeHandlerForMacOS()

    return true
}

func addWindowSizeHandlerForMacOS() {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.compactMap { $0 as? UIWindowScene }.forEach { windowScene in
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 1100)
            windowScene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 1100)
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Example Screenshot

In my app, I defined a function named *addWindowSizeHandlerForMacOS()* starting on line 23. Then I called it from *application()* in *AppDelegate.swift* (line 18).

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

Inside your scene delegate you can do following :

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        scene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 1100)
        scene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 1280, height: 1200)
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Implement Objective-C class with this method:

```
 - (void)setMinimumSize:(CGSize)size {
     id app = NSClassFromString(@"NSApplication");
     id shared = [app valueForKeyPath:@"sharedApplication"];
     id mainWindow = [shared valueForKeyPath:@"mainWindow"];

     NSValue *nssize = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:size];
     [mainWindow setValue:nssize forKeyPath:@"minSize"];
 }
```

To call from Swift - use bridging header.

Comment: yes, that's the way I am doing right now, https://gist.github.com/steipete/30c33740bf0ebc34a0da897cba52fefe

Comment: Can you do full screen on start?

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C version of @marcelosalloum's answer:

```c
for (UIScene* scene in UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes) {
    if ([scene isKindOfClass:[UIWindowScene class]]) {
        UIWindowScene* windowScene = (UIWindowScene*) scene;
        windowScene.sizeRestrictions.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(480, 640);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize` or `sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize` to set minimum or maximum size for your Mac app window.

Open your `SceneDelegate` and:

```swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
   guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

   scene.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 600)
   scene.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 600)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your Scene Delegate:

```
window?.windowScene?.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 900.0, height: 750.0)
```

I also added how to set the maximum size as the greatest possible value:

```
window?.windowScene?.sizeRestrictions?.maximumSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

Comment: SceneDelegate is gone if you have a SwiftUIApp. Do you have a solution for SwiftUIApp?

Comment: @RawMean: Take a look at this post: https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/app-delegate-scene-delegate-swiftui/

Answer (score 0):

I made a small research. So I made the following addition to my SceneDelegate's func scene:

```
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if UIDevice.current.systemName.contains("Mac") {
            window?.windowScene?.sizeRestrictions?.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768)
        } else {
           // iOS - nothing to change
        }
```

I'm not sure that if system name clause is required as the window.windowScene.sizeRestrictoins is nil for iOS, but added this for clear understanding and possible future updates.

I choose 1024x768 as the smallest iPad landscape size (Catalyst reports device as iPad with Mac OS in landscape mode)

Comment: Any idea how to do this when there is no SceneDelegate. When the app is  SwiftUIApp, there is no SceneDelegate