# How do I programmatically minimize/restore the current windows on MAUI (maccatalyst)

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui

I am new to MAUI, and I am trying to port my WPF application so that it runs on Mac Catalyst, and I am blocked trying to port the code that programmatically minimize/restore the current window.

In WPF, it is easy, it is just `this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized`.

I understand that MAUI needs to work on all platform, and minimizing might not make sense for iOS or Android. As far as I can lookup in the `dotnet/maui` repo, there is no API for minimizing windows.

Talking to the MAUI team, they suggested that I can access the underlying native objects and do that natively. Here below is my attempts:

Given the `MainPage` as a `ContentPage`. I have found this:

`this.GetParentWindow().Handler.PlatformView` is an instance of `UIKit.UIWindow` living in `Xamarin.iOS.dll`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiwindow?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) of `UIKit.UIWindow` also has no way to minimize it.

The closest thing that I could find is [NSWindow.PerformMiniaturize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/appkit.nswindow.performminiaturize?view=xamarin-mac-sdk-14), that requires a NSWindow, not a UIWindow. That NSWindows seems to be in a thing called AppKit, not UIKit.

[This](https://github.com/cshung/Tools/tree/private/maui/Calendar/Calendar.Maui) branch contains my attempt to port the application, the WPF application that I am trying to port is right next to it. This is not a huge application, but still quite some amount of code that is unnecessary for this question. If the community provides a tiny sample with a button that when it is clicked the window will minimize, that is good enough I can take it from there.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57123554/199364. Then figure out the c# equivalent.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, thanks. That looks different though - that post is talking about setting a minimum windows size, but I am thinking about minimizing, as in clicking the yellow button. The windows will completely disappear and went to the icons in the bottom of the screen.

Comment: oh you are right! Not sure that is possible. "MacCatalyst" does provide MacOS-specific functionality, but, because it originated from iOS APIs (so app devs can have a single codebase), some details don't seem to be there. :( AFAIK, This is a limitation that has to be fixed by Apple, not Maui.